# Examples of finding eigenfunctions of coupled DEs

Tags: pde, ode, eigenvalues

I am looking for examples of numerically finding eigenvalues/eigenfunctions of coupled DEs. If anyone is able to point me towards any examples, preferably with code included, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A while back I wrote a few such examples over at https://mathematica.stackexchange.com. You can find them [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/57391/18437), [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/85675/18437) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/56320/18437). The last link is probably the best to understand - even though that is not for coupled PDEs; but there is not much difference. There also examples at the reference page of Mathematicas' function [NDEigensystem](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDEigensystem.html) which does what you want.

Let me reproduce a small example here, that is more suited to an audience that may not be as familiar with the language.

To model the modes of a beam we define a plane stress operator (coupled PDE):

```
planeStress = {
 Div[{{0, -((Y*ν)/(1 -ν^2))}, {-(Y*(1 -ν))/(2*(1 - ν^2)), 0}}.Grad[v[t, x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}] + Div[{{-(Y/(1 - ν^2)),  0}, {0, -(Y*(1 - ν))/(2*(1 - ν^2))}}.Grad[u[t, x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}], 
 Div[{{0, -(Y*(1 - ν))/(2*(1 - ν^2))}, {-((Y*ν)/(1 - ν^2)), 0}}.Grad[u[t, x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}] + Div[{{-(Y*(1 -ν))/(2*(1 -ν^2)), 0}, {0, -(Y/(1 - ν^2))}}.Grad[v[t, x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}]
} /. {Y -> 210 10^9, ν -> 33/100};
```

We hold the left hand side of the beam fixed.

```
(*held fixed at left*)
bcs = DirichletCondition[{u[t, x, y] == 0, v[t, x, y] == 0}, x == 0];
```

And call the numerical differential eigensolver:

```
\[Rho] = 7850; length = 10; height = 0.7;
{vals, funs} = 
  NDEigensystem[{Thread[\[Rho]*D[{u[t, x, y], v[t, x, y]}, {t, 1}] == 
      planeStress], 
    DirichletCondition[{u[t, x, y] == 0., v[t, x, y] == 0.}, 
     x == 0]}, {u[t, x, y], v[t, x, y]}, 
   t, {x, y} \[Element] Rectangle[{0, 0}, {length, height}], 9];
```

This returns a list of eigenvalues and eigenfunctions. To plot them:

```
Show[{Graphics3D[
     {Gray, 
      GraphicsComplex[{{0, 0, 0}, {length, 0, 0}, {length, height, 
         0}, {0, height, 0}}, Line[{{1, 2, 3, 4, 1}}]]}],
    Plot3D[
     Sqrt[10000*Total[#^2]], {x, y} \[Element] 
      Rectangle[{0, 0}, {length, height}], 
     ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", Axes -> False, 
     Mesh -> False]}, Boxed -> False] & /@ funs
```

[image]

For more detailed information on how that works, please have a look at the posts I mentioned in the beginning.